# Revising the "stability" tag

Tags: discussion

"Stability" refers to at least two distinct concepts in scientific computing:

- inexactness of floating point arithmetic, backward error analysis, etc
- discretization/operator stability, a necessary part of a well-posed discrete problem

The [stability tag](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stability) claims to be the former, but actually contains more of the latter.  The tag was created *after* several of the defining questions in that category, and really needs to be revised.  Should the [floating-point tag](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/floating-point) be clarified and used to catch those currently using "stability" to mean floating point stability, with "stability" revised for discretization/operator stability?  Or some other scheme?

Answer (score 3):

Both concepts of stability refer to whether small errors have a small impact on the solution.  Only the source of errors differs (roundoff errors versus truncation errors).  I personally think it's fine to have them both under one tag.